# How to apply a patch to a file outside a repository in JGit

Tags: java, git, diff, patch, jgit

I am building a solution to update files for a certain software in Java. I want to create something like the diff/patch Unix functionality, but with Java, for files that are directly in a FS, that is, outside a repository.

At the moment, I could easily get a Diff with JGit by using the following code:

```
public static EditList computeDifferencesGit(final File p_fileOld,
                                             final File p_fileNew) throws IOException
{
    RawText l_contentFileOld = new RawText(p_fileOld);
    RawText l_contentFileNew = new RawText(p_fileNew);

    EditList l_listDiffs = new EditList();
    l_listDiffs.addAll(new HistogramDiff().diff(RawTextComparator.DEFAULT, l_contentFileOld, l_contentFileNew));

    String l_strUnidiff = _getUnidiff(l_contentFileOld, l_contentFileNew, l_listDiffs);
    System.out.println("UNIDIFF:\n" + l_strUnidiff);

    return l_listDiffs;
}
```

However, I would like to apply the results of that diff to a third file as a patch.

I investigated and found there is an `ApplyCommand` class in JGit package. However, to instantiate it, I think I need a repository, which I don't have.

Any idea about how can I apply the patch to the file?

Comment: The ApplyCommand seems to only use the repository to resolve relative file names within the patch. Did you try to provide your own Repository implementation that just returns a suitable getWorkTree()?

Comment: No, I havent tried that yet. In any case I suppose that this is not the intended usage of the class, right? Maybe as a more concrete strategy, I should attempt creating a new temporary repository during the comparison process.

Comment: Right, a custom Repository implementation for this use case is rather not the intended usage. A temporary repository seems to be a better approach.